# ¿Como manejar un servicio que se utilizara en distintos componentes en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, estructuras, modulos

Voy a crear un servicio el cual contiene 2 funciones que trabajan con apis

1.- Obtiene la ip del usuario

2.- Registra la acción que se realizo y la ip del usuario

Este servicio se compartirá con distintos componentes, la idea es que el eliminar, editar y el iniciar sesion manden a llamar ese servicio y ejecutar en el siguiente orden

1. Realiza la acción (eliminar, editar, iniciar sesión)
2. Obtener ip con la función numero 1 de mi servicio
3. Guardar la ip y la acción realizada mediante la función numero 2 de mi servicio

Me interesa saber como es la mejor forma de manejar esto o no pasa nada si invoco estas 3 funciones de forma secuencial.
Por otra parte también me gustaría saber como debería de separar ese servicio en la estructura de mi proyecto si en un servicio de algun componente relacionado, en el modulo de shared, crear alguna carpeta tipo helpers, etc.

Anexo un ejemplo de mi estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No sería más sencillo unificar el paso 2 y 3 en una única llamada? De ese modo el servicio no necesitaría exponer más de una función. El servicio podría obtener la IP si no se obtuvo anteriormente y registrar la acción

Comment: si me parece mas razonable muchas gracias, en cuestión de como manejar el servicio lo incluiría en el servicio de algún componente que hace referencia o en el folder shared?

Comment: Yo prefiero tener los servicios aparte, en una carpeta "services", porque puede ser que más adelante varios componentes lo usen

Comment: todos los componentes requieren de las tres funciones? todos los componentes están dentro de un mismo modulo? implementaste módulos de carga diferida mediante lazy loading? el servicio lo implementas como un singleton mediante providedIn: 'root'?

Comment: La mayoría de los componentes los requerirán y si implemente lazy loading

Comment: En cuestión de la estructura de los componentes cada uno cuenta con su carpeta de servicio, modelo, interfaces etc